# How to create a jaxb.index file on the fly using Ant (or Maven)

Tags: ant, maven, jaxb2

This is more of knowledge sharing rather than asking a question. Thought this little Ant snippet might be useful to someone.

```
<target name="create-jaxb-index" depends="compile">
    <!-- Create a suitable jaxb.index file on the fly to remove the need for an ObjectFactory
         jaxb.index is a simple list of the domain objects without package or extension, e.g.
         org.example.Domain.java -> Domain
    -->
    <fileset id="domain-sources" dir="${src}">
      <include name="org/example/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
    <pathconvert property="domain-list" refid="domain-sources" pathsep="${line.separator}">
      <chainedmapper>
        <flattenmapper/>
        <globmapper from="*.java" to="*" casesensitive="false"/>
      </chainedmapper>
    </pathconvert>
    <echo file="${target}/classes/org/example/jaxb.index" message="${domain-list}"/>
  </target>
```

OK, OK so it doesn't go the whole way and store up all the package names so that it can reconstruct the appropriate file structure, but it's good enough to get you started.

Hope it helps.

Also, you could just insert this little snippet (less the target element) into a Maven build like this:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>
              <!-- Create a suitable jaxb.index file on the fly to remove the need for an ObjectFactory
                   jaxb.index is a simple list of the domain objects without package or extension, e.g.
                   org.example.Domain.java -> Domain
              -->
              <fileset id="domain-sources" dir="${build.sourceDirectory}">
                <include name="org/example/domain/*.java"/>
              </fileset>
              <pathconvert property="domain-list" refid="domain-sources" pathsep="${line.separator}">
                <chainedmapper>
                  <flattenmapper/>
                  <globmapper from="*.java" to="*" casesensitive="false"/>
                </chainedmapper>
              </pathconvert>
              <echo file="${build.outputDirectory}/org/example/domain/jaxb.index" message="${domain-list}"/>
          </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is useful! If you get out by one hair from the intended scope of a framework, then you enter in a hell of quirks and hacks. Sometimes I feel like I am growing tired about Java, Maven, Groovy, etc.

Comment: @boumbh Glad to help. One way to reduce the overwhelming complexity of web development is to try other languages.

Comment: If only I had a choice ^^ . I note the nowadays tendency to use sledgehammers for cracking nuts. JAXB is a very efficient sledgehammer, it cracks my nuts very well (without negative connotation), but sometimes I miss the easy handling of a simpler tool. The problematic would have been different using an other language. Not necessarily better. As some say: "A bad workman always blames his tools. A good workman has the right tools." If I can't choose my tools, that makes me a bad workman.

Comment: @boumbh At work you are limited. But reading "Seven Languages in Seven Weeks" outside of work will introduce you to new approaches that should bring value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the [JAXBIndex plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/JAXBIndex+plugin) from [JAXB2 Basics](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Home).

Answer (score 2):

Following on from Gary's example, I took it and extended it so it would work for more than one package directory. The following should work if you have the antcontrib dependency in your plugin's dependencies:

```
<target>
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" classpathref="maven.dependency.classpath" />
    <for param="dto-dir">
        <path>
            <dirset dir="${basedir}/src/main/java">
                <include name="com/example/**/dto"/>
            </dirset>
        </path>
        <sequential>
            <property name="@{dto-dir}" basedir="${basedir}/src/main/java" relative="true" location="@{dto-dir}" />
            <echo message="Creating jaxb.index file for directory: ${@{dto-dir}}" />
            <echo message="@{dto-dir}" />
            <fileset id="@{dto-dir}_dtos" dir="@{dto-dir}">
                <include name="*Dto.java" />
            </fileset>
            <pathconvert property="@{dto-dir}_contents" refid="@{dto-dir}_dtos" pathsep="${line.separator}">
                <chainedmapper>
                    <flattenmapper />
                    <globmapper from="*.java" to="*" casesensitive="false" />
                </chainedmapper>
            </pathconvert>
            <echo file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/${@{dto-dir}}/jaxb.index" message="${@{dto-dir}_contents}" />                              
        </sequential>
    </for>
</target>
```

I am not an ant expert by any means as you can see, and I had to do some weird stuff to create unique property names, but it works for me.